# Installing torsocks and apt-transport-tor in Zesty

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, torsocks, tor-install

It seems `torsocks` and `apt-transport-tor` don't have installation candidates in Zesty (17.04). I just spent an hr installing and configuring Zesty to my liking only to find these packages aren't available.

Is it safe to use the xenial/universe repos in a Zesty build? Or does it make more sense to install Xenial (16.xx)? How do I install properly install these packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, infact, available for Zesty:

[apt-transport-tor](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/admin/apt-transport-tor) and [torsocks](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/torsocks) are both in the 'universe' repo.

If you want to enable the 'universe' repo, try this question on AskUbuntu: [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: thank you, it seems i had the universe repos disabled in the "Sortware & Updates" GUI. thanks again!